# Updating values in a dict on Python inside a Tkinter button

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I'm attempting to write some code for a game using Python and seem not to be able to get my variables out of the button click command into the dictionary variables for later use. What I'm trying to do is run the jingle_add() on a button click, have it run some calculations, update the displays and return the tree values used and changed back to the appropriate dictionary keys. I can get the code to work if in the jingle_add() I call the dictionary values directly, but I'm trying to compress my code and use this as a template for multiple different types of values that will be saved in the same dictionary, calling them with different buttons. However, with the version of the code below I can't get it to run at all, and no obvious errors are given, only a flag at the lambda line. Is there something I'm missing in the lambda call, or something I missed in the return?

```
data = {'fans': 0, 'jingle': 0, 'jingle_cost': 15}

jingle_button = Button(win, text = "Make a jingle - +0.1 fans/sec", command = lambda: data['fans'], data['jingle_cost'], data['jingle'] = jingle_add(data['fans'], data['jingle_cost'], data['jingle']))

def jingle_add(fans, cost, building):
    if fans >= cost:
        fans -= cost
        cost = round(cost * (1.07**building), 1)
        building += 1
        return fans, cost, building
```

Comment: If anyone wants to see the full code to get a better understanding of what I'm trying to do, it's available at github.com/kari-fox/MixxMaster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its current form, your code cannot compile due to the assignment in the `lambda` expression. An alternative would be to define what that does in a function instead and use the function as the callback:

```
def add_to_data():
    data['fans'], data['jingle_cost'], data['jingle'] = jingle_add(data['fans'], data['jingle_cost'], data['jingle'])

jingle_button = Button(win,
    text = "Make a jingle - +0.1 fans/sec", command = add_to_data)
```

(Note that `add_to_data` does not take parentheses when used as the `command` argument.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was worried about. Is there any way to do that specifically from within the button assignment without having to write a second definition (aka, not using lambda but something else)? Writing a second definition won't help really with combining the code I'm using at the moment, because then I will have to have a separate add_to_data function for each data type I'm using to save them under their respective dictionary keys.

Comment: Depending on how general it needs to be, it should work to use sth like `def add_to_target(target, k1, k2, k3): target[k1], target[k2], target[k3] = jingle_add(target[k1], target[k2], target[k3])`, and then do `Button(..., command = lambda: add_to_target(data, "fans", "jingle", "cost"))`. That way, you would only have one function, and the lambda in each button would specify the actual target and keys.

Comment: Thank you! That wasn't even something I would have thought of. I just added it to the code and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention from where are you getting variable 'cost'.
And try to print something check if its going inside the first loop:

```
if fans >= cost:
```

Your code is correct check for the values your are looping with.